# Inject $log service on simple Jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

Yes, I'm completely new to Angular and Jasmine, and I can't figure out how to inject a mock $log for my test. This is the test:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    describe('basic test', function(){
        it('should just work', function(){
            var $log;

            beforeEach(inject(function(_$log_){
                $log = _$log_;
            }));

            $log.info('it worked!');
            expect($log.info.logs).toContain(['it worked!']);
        });
    });

}())
```

This fails on the inject line with an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'typeName' of undefined
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How's this:

```
describe('basic test', function(){
    var log;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$log_){
        log = _$log_;
    }));

    it('should just work', function(){
        log.info('it worked!');
        expect(log.info.logs).toContain(['it worked!']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the significance of the change? What's different here?

Comment: He moved the `beforeEach` **outside** the `it`  (where it was invisible and ignored) and into the body of the `describe`

Comment: I am literally copying this test, and getting     reference error: " inject is not defined"   Is there a trick to the setup for this?  I have jasmine and ngMocks