# Angular unit testing error: Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, angular-mock

I'm using angular 1.2.2, and angular mock 1.3.5.  It's pretty simple testing code to test my own customized service.

```
angular.module('factories', [])
   .factory('chimp', ['$log', function($log) {
      return {
         ook: function() {
            $log.warn('Ook.');
         }
      };
       }]);

describe('factories', function() {
   var chimp;
   var $log;

   beforeEach(function() {
      module('factories')
      inject(function(_chimp_, _$log_) {
         chimp = _chimp_;
         $log = _$log_;
      })
       });


   beforeEach();

   describe('when invoked', function() {

      beforeEach(function() {
         chimp.ook();
          });

      it('should say Ook', function() {
         expect("1").to.equal('Ook.');
      });
   });
});
```

However, it ways gives me Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
Why is this happening?  angular version does not work with the mock version?

Comment: Try to upgrade your angular to 1.3.x or downgrade your angular mock to 1.2.x.

Comment: Please provide your own answer (based on your comment below) or delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I changed it to 1.2.2 mocks, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some extraneous `beforeEach` statements. Would you mind giving the entire error?

Meanwhile, try this:

```
describe('factories', function() {
   var chimp;
   var $log;

   beforeEach(function() {
      module('factories')
      inject(function(_chimp_, _$log_) {
         chimp = _chimp_;
         $log = _$log_;
      })
   });

   describe('when invoked', function() {
      it('should say Ook', function() {
         chimp.ook();
         expect($log.warn.logs).to.contrail(['Ook.']);
      });
   });
});
```

Also, look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119013/inject-log-service-on-simple-jasmine-test) for a pure Q/A about testing `$log`.

Comment: Thanks.  I kind of think it's because the version is not consistent.  After I changed it to 1.2.2 mocks, it worked.